# How would I add a DATE FORMAT in a query like this?

Tags: date, format

```
    (SELECT o.obs_result FROM observations AS o
    INNER JOIN encounters_link elobs ON elobs.linked_id=o.obs_id AND elobs.module=3
    WHERE o.obs_code=@bbp_date_injury AND elobs.encounter_id = e.encounter_id
    ORDER BY o.observed_datetime DESC LIMIT 1
    ) AS 'Date of Injury'
```

I've tried to add a line to FORMAT before the WHERE clause but I keep getting an error